# @observable prefix in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I was researching something that I found this snippet:

```
class Todo {
    id = Math.random();
    @observable title = "";
    @observable finished = false;
}
```

- What is "@observale" before the fields?
- And what is it's applicability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an annotation, which is not provided by default. It is added by the dependency to https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx